# Move same git tag to the latest push using Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, tags

I have a Jenkins build configured to run on each push, I want to tag the latest push with a `latest` tag for a process that runs on pushes with that tag only.

I've tried to create a post-build event that updates a `latest` tag on the `origin` remote name, but that works only the first time, next push will cause a `Updates were rejected because the tag already exists in the remote.` error.

Here's my configuration in Jenkins:
[image: My Jenkins configuration]

Any ideas on how to remove the old `latest` tag and move it to the newly pushed version on Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

Just execute a script before you tag which deletes the previous latest tag:

```
# delete local tag 'latest'
git tag -d latest
# delete remote tag 'latest' (eg, GitHub version too)
git push origin :refs/tags/latest
```

reference [here](https://gist.github.com/mobilemind/7883996).

Comment: Thanks for replying! Where do I put this script in Jenkins? Can't find any place to run custom post-build scripts in there

Comment: True, to execute a post build step script you can use the https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task plugin. Or to make it easier (to test) you can just add a 'execute shell' as last step of your build and after implement the plugin.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this without installing 3rd party plugins?

Comment: Just use the execute shell as last step of your build. Then you don't need any plugin